# SSL verification error with git (on github) on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, git, openssl, curl

I'm trying to clone the atom repository that [just went fully open-source](http://blog.atom.io/2014/05/06/atom-is-now-open-source.html) and I've run into some trouble.

Attempting to `git clone` the repository is producing an SSL error:

```
wug@wugputer:/src/test$ git clone https://github.com/atom/atom.git
Cloning into atom...
error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed while accessing https://github.com/atom/atom.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Googling has indicated that this is a failing CURL call, and that there is an environment variable I can set to get more information, but it's not showing anything particularly useful:

```
wug@wugputer:/src/test$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone https://github.com/atom/atom.git
Cloning into atom...
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to proxy proxy.wugcorp.com port 3128 (#0)
*   Trying 10.1.2.3... * Connected to proxy.wugcorp.com (10.1.2.3) port 3128 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to github.com:443
> CONNECT github.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: github.com:443
User-Agent: git/1.7.4.1
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established
< 
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* Connected to proxy.wugcorp.com (10.1.2.3) port 3128 (#0)
* SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
* Expire cleared
* Closing connection #0
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to proxy proxy.wugcorp.com port 3128 (#0)
*   Trying 10.1.2.3... * Connected to proxy.wugcorp.com (10.1.2.3) port 3128 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to github.com:443
> CONNECT github.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: github.com:443
User-Agent: git/1.7.4.1
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established
< 
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* Connected to proxy.wugcorp.com (10.1.2.3) port 3128 (#0)
* SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
* Expire cleared
* Closing connection #0
error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed while accessing https://github.com/atom/atom.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I'm at work, proxy.wugcorp.com is our web proxy (it's expected to be there).  I've been able to git clone things as recently as last week without any issues.  I'm also able to `curl` the file git's complaining about without doing any funny tricks:

```
wug@wugputer:/src/test$ curl https://github.com/atom/atom.git/info/refs
Please upgrade your git client.
GitHub.com no longer supports git over dumb-http: https://github.com/blog/809-git-dumb-http-transport-to-be-turned-off-in-90-days
```

openssl also reports that the certificate is fine:

```
wug@wugputer:/src/test$ openssl s_client -connect github.com:443 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 businessCategory = Private Organization, 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3 = US, 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2 = Delaware, serialNumber = 5157550, street = 548 4th Street, postalCode = 94107, C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = "GitHub, Inc.", CN = github.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/businessCategory=Private Organization/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware/serialNumber=5157550/street=548 4th Street/postalCode=94107/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=GitHub, Inc./CN=github.com
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
 1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/businessCategory=Private Organization/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware/serialNumber=5157550/street=548 4th Street/postalCode=94107/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=GitHub, Inc./CN=github.com
issuer=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3233 bytes and written 443 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: B5209FBCD0437CE4443399C5488071EAF6236ED8C489C0EF62E73A4453E3AB7C
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 61E892AA74B881B7CE7C69DD0843B282BCAF6646282BB8099C2D3D84C63F3D311211822FB129432AE112A7E99BF07BCB
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1399403523
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

The weirdest thing though, is that the original git clone call will REPRODUCIBLY WORK if I run it in strace.

```
wug@wugputer:/src/test$ strace git clone https://github.com/atom/atom.git
[lots of output snipped]
[works correctly]
```

I have no idea what's going on.  Why is git so angry at github.com's certificate, when everything else is ok with it? and more importantly, why does the issue disappear when I attempt to inspect it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your traffic goes through a proxy:

```
 About to connect() to proxy proxy.wugcorp.com port 3128
```

The error message:

```
certificate verify failed while accessing https://github.com/atom/atom.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

makes me think that for some reason the proxy doesn't serve this particular request. It might not be getting through for some reason. I'd suggest you have someone look in the proxy server logs.

Comment: Good catch - @Wug any chance they're doing inline SSL decrypt on the proxy (Bluecoat or such) that might be providing a different PKI?